# Is my webcam hardwired?

Tags: malware, virus, spyware, trojan

I want to know if my webcam LED can be controlled by software (malware) or if it is hardwired. My understanding is that if a webcam's LED is hardwired it cannot be turned on by a hacker without the LED turning on. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I am running a DELL Inspirion 15 5000 series that I bought recently.

I tried running this command uvcdynctrl -c and I don't get the LED option so does this mean it is hardwired ?

Comment: Just put tape\sticker over the camera when it is not in use. If you have RAT software running on your PC then you have bigger concerns. You should be trying to prevent this scenario. Detecting an infection by observing hardware behavior is too little, too late.

Comment: "if a webcam's LED is hardwired" - This is false